# Undefined viewmodel id

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a viewModel:

```
var teamViewModel = {
        teams: ko.observableArray([]),
        selectedTeam: ko.observable(1),
        clearTeams: function(){
            this.teams.removeAll();
        },
        addTeam: function (id, name, isChecked) {
            t = new team(id, name, isChecked);
            this.teams.push(t);
        }
    };
```

I want the selectedTeam().id to be initialized as 1, but every time a function is called on page load which references `teamViewModel.selectedTeam().id` the value is returned as undefined.

How can I initialize this value to 1 before the the function is called?

Comment: In your sample `selectedTeam` holds the integer value `1` and there is no `id` property on integer that is way `teamViewModel.selectedTeam().id` is undefined. You need something like: `selectedTeam: ko.observable({id: 1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `selectedTeam` with a new instance of `team`:

```
selectedTeam: ko.observable(new team(1, "", false))
```